# how make a looped animation wait using css3

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a css3 animation with the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.animated {
-webkit-animation-name: rotate;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2.4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

It works flawlessly, well..., I want to make it wait between the loops: 
*animation-start*, animation-finish, **wait(about 0.5s)**, *animation start*, animation end, **wait(about 0.5s)**...

PS: I've tried `-webkit-animation-delay`, it does not work.

Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add 0.5 seconds to your animation duration, then create an extra frame in your `keyframes` that doesn't change the rotation amount;

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    83% { /*2.4 / 2.9 = 0.827*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.animated {
...
-webkit-animation-duration: 2.9s; /*note the increase*/
...
}
```

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/ZVgAu/).

Comment: A little "workaround" to what Abody97 did: [webkit animation fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVgAu/1/)

Comment: Beautiful solution, why didn't this immediately pop into my head?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the css class on element for a specified time by javascript might solve your problem.

```
function delayAnimation () {
    var animatedEl = document.getElementById('whatever');
    animatedEl.className = '';
    setTimeout(function () {
        animatedEl.className = 'animated'
        setTimeout(delayAnimation, 2400);// i see 2.4s is your animation duration
    }, 500)// wait 0.5s
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit : I updated this answer to fix the code. You can see a fully working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6C7L/1/). Thanks to [@Fabrice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580717/fabrice) for pointing out the code was not working.

Comment: you are welcome. i personally liked @Abody97 's answer better too when i saw it :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a transition.
For example:

```
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
```

where `transition-delay:0.6s;`